# Remove original sender address from "send mail as" in Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I have a gmail address, say me@gmail.com, and I also have my own domain, say mydomain.com. I use Google Apps on mydomain.com. I use many different email addresses on mydomain.com, and I don't want to log into each of those accounts to check my email. I want to see all my email in one mailbox. So I just have mydomain.com forward all incoming email to me@gmail.com as a catch-all address and use that as my single inbox.

When I send mail from me@gmail.com I can choose "send mail as" one of the mydomain.com aliases. It then has the mydomain.com address in the "from" field, BUT me@gmail.com still appears in one or more fields in the headers, such as the "sender" field. That defeats some of the main purposes for having the domain in the first place. For several reasons I don't want any trace of me@gmail.com in the outgoing email headers.

The workaround solution I've been using is to log into the relevant mydomain.com mailbox, compose a new message, and copy the recipient and the subject and (if necessary) the quoted email into it. I have to do this for every single email I send. Obviously not ideal.

Is there a better way? That is to say: Is there a way to send mail from the me@gmail.com catch-all, choose "send mail as" someone@mydomain.com, and not have me@gmail.com appear anywhere in the headers?

Comment: I have a very similar problem: I set up gmail with an embarrassing username I created as a teenager which friends and family use (let's call it *lolz@gmail.com*), then later created a serious email account (*my.name@gmail.com*) which I set as the `default` and `send mail as` for all mail - but I was recently shocked to discover that emails sent `from` *my.name@gmail.com* had  *lolz@gmail.com* as the `sender`, showing on some email clients as  *my.name@gmail.com via lolz@gmail.com*... Did you ever find a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

I do this also, and it works fine for me, but all of my email addresses are @mydomain.com. You may have to use one of the emails in the account @mydomain.com as your base rather than your @gmail.com.

That also might be better if you have less of an issue if your @mydomain.com remains in the header when you use @gmail.com as your sender.

Not sure it's the perfect solution, but maybe better than your current one.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps for Business supports delegation, so you easily can dip in and out of the various mailboxes you have.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350

You could also consolidate your multiple gApps mailboxes into one inside gApps, and use Send As in the same way. You could then create filters to automatically label incoming mail to keep the different streams separate.

Also consider using Groups.

But give up on your @gMail.com account for these purposes.

Answer (score -1):

When you click create account it will automatically put @gmail.com at the end. If you type the whole email address you want, for example me@mydomain.com the @gmail.com will disappear and you can log in to gmail through an email that is not @gmail.com